# Tracking KeyUp and KeyDown of multiple keys at once

Tags: c#, time, event-handling, keyboard-events, keyevent

I need to monitor how long the user holds down each key when typing. So far I have used a keyBoard event handler and started a stopwatch at e.KeyDown and stopped it a e.KeyUp. This works fine until a user holds two buttons down at once, eg holding the shift key when capitalizing. My code:

```
 public partial class LoginPage : Form
    {
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Stopwatch KeyStopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        Stopwatch KeyStopWatch2 = new Stopwatch();

        private void textBoxUsername_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            KeyStopWatch.Start();

        }


        private void textBoxUsername_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

            KeyStopWatch.Stop();


            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Desktop\KeyTimes.txt", true))
            {

                file.Write(e.KeyCode + " ");
                file.WriteLine(KeyStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            }

            KeyStopWatch.Reset();
            KeyStopWatch2.Reset();
        }
    }
```

This is the example output I get, one without caps the others with, there are errors in both by the way

```
T 153
H 0
I 89
S 89
Space 111
I 73
S 105
Space 126
A 121
Space 132
T 253
S 0
E 0
T 116

Space 95

T 248
ShiftKey 0
H 89
I 95
S 89
Space 111
I 116
S 100
Space 126
A 111
Space 122
T 407
ShiftKey 0
E 185
S 132
T 84
```

My question; is there anyway to efficiently track the timing of each key without writing an event for each specific key?

EDIT: What I'm trying to say is, is there away of tracking the timing of two keys independently if pressed at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question, but I would use a `Dictionary<Keys, Stopwatch>` to track the times. As keys for the Dictionary I would use the lower-case character of each pressed key.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<Keys, Stopwatch> _stopwatches = new Dictionary<Keys, Stopwatch>();

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        _stopwatches[e.KeyCode] = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text += e.KeyCode;

        Stopwatch stopwatch;
        if (_stopwatches.TryGetValue(e.KeyCode, out stopwatch))
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            textBox2.Text += " " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms";
        }

        textBox2.Text += Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

textBox1 is the input box.
textBox2 is the output box, but you could use your text file here as well.

Comment: The problem is that if I press two keys at once it cant keep track of both keys at the same time

Comment: Sorry , I think I misunderstood you. Im trying your dictionary idea but I have no idea how to populate the dictionary with each keycode